# suggestion regarding use of foreign key and value and master tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have different tables in my `SQL server` `database` and most tables references fields like status (of a particular object), category (of a particular object), type (of a particular object) etc. where these statuses, categories and types etc. come from separate master tables of their own (e.g. table for StatusMaster etc.).

I want to know what is the best practice:
a) the status/category/type fields in the main tables should be `varchar`/`text` type fields representing the values from the master tables
b) or they should be `foreign keys` (`int`)

I think ideally it should be done using (b) i.e. foreign keys because if whenever master table entry is changed (e.g. status "In Progress" is changed to "Work Started") all corresponding entries will get automatically updated wherever they are referenced. But, my problem is that I have too many tables in my application (70+), and so many different statuses/categories/types etc. so it becomes a headache to maintain so many tables.

Also, please suggest
I should have a single table which contains master information for statues, categories, types (and any other as required) with an additional field which tells what kind of master entry it is, or its better to have separate tables as I have now?

Comment: With a single status table and type column, you would need to also store the type in referencing (FK) tables to enforce referential integrity. Separate tables is a more correct model. Not sure why that's difficult to maintain for you but the best practice is to keep both the DDL and domain data under source control. As to the status data type, I generally use a mnemonic code (e.g. char(1) with values like 'P', 'S', 'C' for in progress, work started, completed, etc.) but that is primarily opinion based. There is no single best practice.

Comment: I think rule of thumb in these type of scenarios is to adjust the data layer for both the application, and database's sake. Whilst referential integrity is good, it is also often a cause for .NET to throw an error when you use DML statements on the data sets. You also wouldnt want to have the status on multiple tables. That is just redundant. You want to have an ID that you can reference to other tables with a status linked to it.

Answer (score 0):

Current status :

- You have 70+ tables.
- All tables have references fields like status, category, type
- Status, Category, Type has master table

**Best practice approach a)**
The status/category/type fields in the main tables should be varchar/text type fields representing the values from the master tables

- Here you have to apply 3 fields in all 70+ table for status/category/type with `varchar(50)`
- The Problem, if Master table value change like "In Progress" to "Work Started", here you need update apply update query to all 70+ tables.  (`Update` query for Master table)
- Performance will be slower, if you need to use `where` condition to search in there field

**Best practice approach b)** or they should be `foreign keys (int)`

- Here you have to apply 3 fields in all 70+ table for status/category/type with `int` datatype
- You need to use `left outer join` for 3 times for each 70+ table to in `select` query

Ex:

```
Select myTable.*, tblMaster1.StatusName, tblMaster2.CategoryName, tblMaster3.TypeName
From myTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblMaster as tblMaster1 ON tblMaster1.MasterID = myTable.StatusIDF
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblMaster as tblMaster2 ON tblMaster2.MasterID = myTable.CategoryIDF
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblMaster as tblMaster3 ON tblMaster3.MasterID = myTable.TypeIDF
```

- Above query will decrease sql server performance

**Best practice approach c)**
Apply 6 fields, 3 fields for `foreign keys (int)` and 3 fields for `varchar(50)`  in the main tables.

- You need to write `Update` query for Master table on value change like "In Progress" to "Work Started"
- But first advantage is the you don't need to use `Join` to get related value from Master table
- Second advantage is you have `foreign keys` too in that table, if you need to use join or fire any query or sub query using `where` clause in status/category/type, you need use `foreign keys` field it will improve performance because its `int` datatype
- Third advantage, You will have freedom to chose (to switch between)  `int`  or `varchar(50)` fields as per your business logic requirement.

So as per my opinion, you have to go with option **c)** it will be helpful for long term  benefits